# Why UITableViewCell needs to be registered?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell, reusability

these are all codes in my demo:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var numberOfCell = 0

    @IBAction func addAction() {
        numberOfCell = numberOfCell + 1
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberOfCell + 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstCell", for: indexPath)
                let addButton = cell.viewWithTag(99) as! UIButton
                return cell
            } else {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SecondCell", for: indexPath)
                let deleteButton = cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UIButton
                let textField = cell.viewWithTag(101) as! UITextField
                return cell
            }
        } else {
            return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

I set cells' identifier in Attributes inspector at storyboard file, didn't register the cells, everything goes right like this:

[Tap Add button, show a new cell with a button and a textfield.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq7i5.png)

But in my project, I use the same way, when I tap Add button, the app will crash, and report this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier SecondCell - must register a nib or a class for
>   the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I have tried register cell use this code:

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SecondCell")
```

But if I do this, the app will crash at `let deleteButton = cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UIButton` and `let textField = cell.viewWithTag(101) as! UITextField` because them are nil.

I think my project and demo have no differences, I don't know how to deal with this issues.

Comment: You must register all the cells upfront which you are going to use in tableview.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register .   This is explanation.

Comment: Please, don't use tags. Use outlets. Tags are just a bad replacements for outlets, don't do that to your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nib file then you need to register your cell in the tableview.

```
 self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "nibName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier")
```